# Suggestions for an iPhone app for contacts

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications, contacts

I am looking for an iPhone app for our sales team that would allow them to do the following:

- Group contacts into custom groups
- Add meeting notes against a contact
- Locate contacts on a map (optional provide directions from current location)
- Store extra images such as business card against a contact
- Doesn't screw up Outlook contacts

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that appears to do what you want, and happens to be free:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ycontacts/id340140852?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use something like [Bento or FileMaker](http://www.filemaker.com.au/products/iphone/).

Comment: "wildly popular personal database" - I love marketing folks.

Comment: haha yeah. Its not a bad app, but it nowhere as great as they think it is :)